# abbreviations do not expand

Tags: abbrev

My abbreviations are not expanding when I type the abbreviations

I have the following in my `~/.emacs` for initiating the abbrev mode

```
(setq-default abbrev-mode t)

(setq save-abbrevs t)

(setq abbrev-file-name "~/abbrev.el")

(if (file-readable-p abbrev-file-name)
  (read-abbrev-file abbrev-file-name))

(dolist (hook '(erc-mode-hook
                emacs-lisp-mode-hook
                text-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook #'abbrev-mode))
```

I get the following message saying that the abbreviation file is loaded

```
Loading /Users/baburaj/abbrev.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Mark set
Automatic display of crossref information was turned on
Applying style hooks...
Loading /Users/baburaj/auto/junk.el (source)...done
Loading /Users/baburaj/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-12.2.0/style/article.elc...do
Applying style hooks...done
Sorting environment...done
Removing duplicates...done
Mark set
```

I also get the following when I type `M-x list-abbrev`

```
(text-mode-abbrev-table)

";af"          1    "aerofoil"
```

However when I type `;af` it does not expand to `aerofoil`

What is the error that I am making? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode#toc4):

`M-x abbrev-mode` toggles Abbrev mode.

*Either*, you want Abbrev mode always on, everytime/everywhere, then you put the following in your ~/.emacs file: `(setq-default abbrev-mode t)`

*Either* you want Abbrev mode on, **but only for the some modes**, for example: `erc-mode`, `emacs-lisp-mode`, `text-mode`, in this case, you can put in your ~/.emacs file:

```
    ;; enable Abbrev mode only for erc, emacs-lisp, and text modes
    (dolist (hook '(erc-mode-hook
                    emacs-lisp-mode-hook
                    text-mode-hook))
      (add-hook hook #'abbrev-mode))
```

Now, it is also written [in another part of the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expanding-Abbrevs.html#Expanding-Abbrevs) that:

> and any word-constituent character can be part of an abbrev.

A `;` is not word constituent, unless you [want](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable#toc4) it to be. So `a semicolon can't be part of an abbrev`.

Maybe it's time to write some [Fortran](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fortran-Abbrev.html) :)

Comment: Thank you, I removed the ; in my abbreviations and it worked. I was using XEmacs earlier and ; used to work there. Had tried using my same abbreviations file in GNU Emacs too.